# History of operator precendence

Tags: arithmetic, math-history

I have seen a lot of debates over operator precedence but what is the history of operator precedence and how it evolved over time? Why multiplication precedes addition; Is it just to be definitive?

These are the two close links that I could find based on this topic

- [History of the order of operations](https://web.archive.org/web/20180111045655/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52582.html)
- [Debate on the order of operations](https://web.archive.org/web/20180123214438/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/57021.html)

But there are no definite answers in both of them.

Comment: If you want a more definite answer than what can be found in the two (excellent) references you provide, then I think you need to be more specific in your question. Basically, it evolved naturally together with symbolic notation in the 16th century, but the Devil is in the details, as your references clearly show...